# Move objects from one index to a particular index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and currently using an array of object

```
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name: 'eve'},{name:'john'},
               {name:'john'}{name:'john'},{name:'mon'},{name:'mon'},
               {name:'paul'},{name:'paul'},{name:'paul'}];
```

what i want is to place all the objects having value 'paul' to be after value 'eve'

```
var arrOfObj = [{name: 'eve'},{name: 'eve'},{name:'paul'},
               {name:'paul'}{name:'paul'},{name:'mon'},{name:'mon'},
               {name:'john'},{name:'john'},{name:'john'}];
```

Comment: None of the objects has a `paul` key. They all have only one key -> `name`. The value of the `name` key is `'paul'` for some of them

Comment: The expected result has 5 `'paul'`s. Where do the other two come from? And the order is not as described.

Comment: You want to have a look at [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: There's no generic solution for this, you've to know the values of the names before rearranging the array.

Comment: What if the objects having "eve" are not consecutive?

Comment: is there a **general** rule, how the objects should be sorted?

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem, what are you trying to achieve with the array rearragement? Why it's needed in the first place?

Comment: @trincot they are consecutive by default

Comment: It seems your question is more about moving "john" to the end. Because in the expected result you have also swapped john and tom. This seems all very specific. What if there is a "helen" or "bob" or "jack"... any rules for them? Can you *explain* why you need exceptions like that?

Comment: @trincot i wanted to shift paul to 2nd position (after eve)

Comment: Yeah, both "paul" and "john" moved, please explain the exact sorting logic needed.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I'm considering it a sorted array(replaced tom with mon), the sort logic i want is to move objects having value paul should be at 2nd position(after eve)

Comment: `arrOfObj.sort((a, b) => a.name !== 'eve' && b.name === 'paul' ? 1 : 0);` does the trick, but it moves only `paul` in the array. This will work strictly with this particular case only. If the array is very large, this method might be slow, then you should consider to first find all the pauls and then splice the array (twice) accordingly.

Comment: @Teemu that sort fn won't work if the pauls are in the array before the eves, right?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Right, but OP has only specified this single order of the members in the array, as I said, it works for this particular case only.

Comment: @amanbisht39 ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @amanbisht39 ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach was to use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a combination of a custom (the OP specific) [compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) and helper compare functions where the latter solve the task of assuring an ascending sort order in the most possible generic way by also utilizing [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for string type arguments.

***Edit** according to Teemu's comment*

**Note** ... please OP be aware of that ...

> *"With a couple of ten thousands of names this will be dead slow. –
> Teemu
> "*

```js
var arrOfObj = [
  { name: 'mon' },
  { name: 'paul' },
  { name: 'john' },
  { name: 'paul' },
  { name: 'mon' },
  { name: 'eve' },
  { name: 'eve' },
  { name: 'john' },
  { name: 'paul' },
  { name: 'john' },
];
// OP ... what i want is to place all the objects
//    having value 'paul' to be after value 'eve'.

function defaultCompareAscending(a, b) {
  return ((a < b) && -1) || ((a > b) && 1) || 0;
}
function compareAscending(a, b) {
  return (a.localeCompare && b.localeCompare)
    ? a.localeCompare(b)
    : defaultCompareAscending(a, b);
}

console.log(
  "shallow copy sorted ascending by name ...",
  [...arrOfObj]
    .sort((a, b) => compareAscending(a.name, b.name))
);
console.log(
  "shallow copy sorted to the OP's conditions ...",
  [...arrOfObj]
    .sort(({ name: aName }, { name: bName}) => {

      aName = aName.toLowerCase();
      bName = bName.toLowerCase();

      return (
        (aName === 'paul' && bName === 'eve') && 1
      ) || (
        (aName === 'eve' && bName === 'paul') && -1
      ) || (
        aName === 'paul' && -1
      ) || (
        bName === 'paul' && 1
      ) || compareAscending(aName, bName);
    })
);
console.log(
  "unsorted original `arrOfObj` reference ...",
  { arrOfObj }
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: With a couple of ten thousands of names this will be dead slow.

Comment: @Teemu ... you are definitely right ... thanks for mentioning it. I should have stated it to the OP within my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A parametrizable method would be like below, it also suits for large arrays.

```js
const arrOfObj = [
  {name: 'eve'},
  {name: 'eve'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'tom'},
  {name: 'tom'},
  {name: 'paul'},
  {name: 'paul'},
  {name: 'paul'}
];

function moveAfter(source, target, array) {
  if (!array.find(({name}) => name === source)) {return array;} // Quit, no source found
  if (!array.find(({name}) => name === target)) {return array;} // Quit, no target found
  const from = array.findIndex(({name}) => name === source),
    count = array.reduce((acc, {name}, index) => name === source ? index : acc, -1) - from + 1,
    values = array.splice(from, count),
    to = array.reduce((acc, {name}, index) => name === target ? index : acc, -1) + 1;
  array.splice(to, 0, ...values);
  return array;
}

console.log(moveAfter('paul', 'eve', arrOfObj));
```

The code "moves pauls after eves in arrOfObj" in-place. And also eves after pauls, or what ever other names are passed, providing name objects are grouped by the names, and both the names are present in the array, if not, the function does nothing.

The function first searches the first index of param 1, then the last index of it, making the length for `splice` to cut the name objects. The position where to start to add the moved group is the last index of the param 2. The first `splice` then cuts the names to move from the array, and the second `splice` inserts the values into correct place. The complex looking `reduce`s emulate "Array.findLastIndex` method, which currently doesn't exist in JS.

This way the array is reindexed only twice, time expensive sorting is not needed, hence the algorithm can be used with large arrays too.

You can test the code with other parameters at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m2g4a0v/).

Answer (score 0):

I propose you manually handle the array without resorting to the `sort` function because I am not seeing any general sorting logic in your request.

What you can do is find the pauls, remove them from the array, then find the eves, and insert the removed pauls right after them.

The solution below assumes that, just like you mentioned, all objects with the same name are right next to one another and not scattered across the array.

```js
const arrOfObj = [
    { name: 'eve' }, { name: 'eve' },
    { name:'john' }, { name:'john' }, { name:'john' },
    { name:'tom' }, { name:'tom' },
    { name:'paul' }, { name:'paul' }, { name:'paul' }
];
// get first and last indexes of paul
const firstPaulIndex = arrOfObj.findIndex(({ name }) => (name === 'paul'));
const lastPaulIndex = arrOfObj.length - 1 - arrOfObj.slice().reverse().findIndex(({ name }) => (name === 'paul'));

// remove the pauls from the array
const splicedPauls = arrOfObj.splice(firstPaulIndex, lastPaulIndex - firstPaulIndex + 1);

// get the last index of eve after the removal
const lastEveIndex = arrOfObj.length - 1 - arrOfObj.slice().reverse().findIndex(({ name }) => (name === 'eve'));

// insert the pauls right after the eves
arrOfObj.splice(lastEveIndex + 1, 0, ...splicedPauls);
console.log(arrOfObj);
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as Peter's code, copying and reversing a large array multiple times are memory and time consuming operations.

Comment: @Teemu assuming the thing you're looking for is at the end of the array, you think reducing to get the count is faster then reversing to find the index of last?

Comment: It definitely is, `slice` alone will take as much time as the entire `reduce` method in my answer, on the top of that you'll reverse the array, together those will double the time, and no memory consumption of three arrays instead of a single array was mentioned yet ; ).

Comment: I see, and I just saw that the reverse function is around 1.5n pretty much, so I agree.